# "Playground execution failed" thrown when importing UIKit

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcplayground

I am trying to play around with UIKit in playgrounds and i have consistently found the following error:

"
Playground execution failed: expression failed to parse, unknown error
* thread #1: tid = 0xc9c7, 0x00000001067253c0 Test`executePlayground, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001067253c0 Test`executePlayground
    frame #1: 0x00000001067249c0 Test`__37-[XCPAppDelegate enqueueRunLoopBlock]_block_invoke + 32
    frame #2: 0x000000010723f25c CoreFoundation`**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
    frame #3: 0x0000000107224304 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
    frame #4: 0x0000000107223a75 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 901
    frame #5: 0x0000000107223494 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    frame #6: 0x000000010c631a6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #7: 0x0000000107dce964 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #8: 0x00000001067246e9 Test`main + 201
    frame #9: 0x000000010a78168d libdyld.dylib`start + 1=
"

Here are more details:
XCode version: 8.1
OSX version: 10.11.5

Code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
var str1 = str
```

Just by following statement

```
 import UIKit
```

I get the above error. At the same time i am not even able to 
import PlaygroundSupport since it doesnt comes up in auto completion.

I am getting this consistently while i am trying to run the 
sample codes from apple or any other playground sample having UIKit.
I tried looking up the issue using all possible queries on stackoverflow and finally decided to post this one.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Sincere Thanks